# Find the integral of $(z^5+3z^3+4z^2+1)*e^{\frac1{z^2}}$dz

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, power-series

I first take the power series of $e^{\frac{1}{z^2}}$ as $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)^n}{n!}$, multiple by that by ($z^5+3z^3+4z^2+1$) and end up with $\int_{|z|=1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)^n}{n!}(z^5+3z^3+4z^2+1)dz$ and end up stuck after that. I was told that after expanding, I should take the "negative z term" and that would allow me to solve the integral, but I'm not sure how to retrieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $(z^5+3z^3+4z^2+1)e^\frac{1}{z^2}=(z^5+3z^3+4z^2+1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}z^{-2n}=(z^5+3z^3+4z^2+1)(1+z^{-2}+\frac{1}{2}z^{-4}+\frac{1}{6}z^{-6}+\dots)=\frac{5}{3}z^{-1}+\dots$

so $\text{Res}_0(f)=\frac{5}{3}$, hence $\oint_{|z|=1}f(z)dz=2\pi i\cdot\frac{5}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

Hints: we have for $m \in \mathbb N_0$:

$z^m e^{1/z^2}= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}z^{m-2k}$

This series converges uniformly on $|z|=1$. Hence

$ \int_{|z|=1}z^m e^{1/z^2} dz=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{k!}z^{m-2k}dz$.

For $j \in \mathbb Z$ we have

$\int_{|z|=1} z^j dz =0$ if $j?ne -1$ and $\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{z} dz = 2 \pi i$.

Your turn !